# Do the words 'Where' and 'Wherever' mean the same in this sentence?

Tags: formality, legalese, where

I'm reading a sentence of Intellectual Property law and I've found this:

> [Where] other Acts related to intellectual property are enacted or amended, they shall satisfy the objectives and basic principles of this Act.

Does "where" have the same meaning as "wherever"?

If it does, can "where", which has a meaning of "wherever", be used in such formal sentences as the law or legal documents?

Comment: In the cited context, ***wherever*** is an "emphatic" alternative to ***where***. But a "stylistic choice" like that is unusual in the context of *legal* texts, so at least *some* readers will try to come up with a *reason* for the unusual choice. Personally, if I saw ***wherever*** in this context, my first guess would be that it's from a fake news source trying to promote a non-existent law.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

"Where" means "In cases which". See [B2 in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where):

> used when referring to a particular stage in a process or activity

"Wherever" would mean the same according to [B2 of its entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wherever) (Both being B2 is a coincidence):

> in every case

Neither "where" nor "wherever" are informal.

Similar constructions would be:

- Where you need help, ask the teacher.
- Where Jenny is mentioned, her name must be capitalized.
- Wherever you see a scratch, paint over it.

Answer (score 2):

FumbleFingers is spot on with

- [here,]  'wherever' is an *emphatic* alternative to 'where'.

[Oxford Languages {courtesy of Google}](https://www.google.com/search?q=wherever+meaning&sca_esv=594218892&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=E26NZa6tH9HQhbIPm4GqmAc&ved=0ahUKEwjugoXnlLKDAxVRaEEAHZuACnMQ4dUDCBE&uact=5&oq=wherever+meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEHdoZXJldmVyIG1lYW5pbmcyChAAGIAEGEYY-QEyBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBRAAGIAEMgYQABgHGB4yBRAAGIAEMiEQABiABBhGGPkBGJcFGIwFGN0EGEYY9AMY9QMY9gPYAQFI-BRQAFiYEHAAeAGQAQCYAYEBoAGTBqoBAzkuMbgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGIAEGIoFGEPCAg0QABiABBiKBRhDGLEDwgIOEAAYgAQYigUYkQIYsQPCAgsQABiABBiKBRiRAsICEBAAGIAEGIoFGEMYsQMYgwHCAgsQABgHGB4YRhj_AcICBxAAGIAEGArCAhcQABgHGB4YRhj_ARiXBRiMBRjdBNgBAcICChAAGIAEGLEDGArCAg0QABiABBixAxhGGPkBwgIkEAAYgAQYsQMYRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEBwgILEAAYBxgeGEYY-QHCAiIQABgHGB4YRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEBwgIMEAAYgAQYDRhGGPkBwgIHEAAYgAQYDcICIxAAGIAEGA0YRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEBwgIhEAAYgAQYRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEB4gMEGAAgQeIDBRIBMSBAiAYBugYGCAEQARgT&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) includes [combining comment on a separate sense]:

> **wherever**: in every case when [(emphasising a lack of restriction)]

The conjunctions can also, of course, be used in their prototypical spatial sense

> - *Where there is water there is life.* [common generalisation, obviously hyperbolic; Neil deGrasse Tyson for instance] ['wherever' would work at least as well semantically here, with a nod to the hyperbole, but isn't as punchy]

> - *There will be swarms of living things wherever the water of this river flows.* [[Ezekiel 47:9; NLT;
>   BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/ezekiel/47-9.htm)]

Though both words (in this usage, as conjunctions) essentially mean 'in every place / situation that', 'where' tends to be the choice in those cases where there is in practice less universality. So its true meaning in such cases is 'in most/many places that/where' ... 'typically' is the pragmatic force.

The third example below might well be challenged as imprecise, too strong a claim, if 'wherever' were substituted:

- *You go to where there is need*. [[National Catholic Reporter](https://www.ncronline.org/news/catholic-worker-you-go-where-there-need-part-1)]
- *It operates as a funnel for western governments to send aid where they would not want to be seen operating*. [[Sunday Times; Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/send-aid)]
- *Where there are no safety barriers, accidents happen*.

(In the first example, 'wherever' would probably be acceptable to most people, the connotation being 'any place at all', emphasising the universality of *opportunity* rather than complete coverage.

In the second, 'all those places [in which they would not want to be seen operating, but do actually operate]' certainly licenses 'wherever'.)

................

As regards register, 'wherever' is probably at least slightly more formal, [??'Wherever there's muck, there's brass']  but neither is out of place in a formal document etc on grounds of register.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how often ***whenever*** occurs instead of ***when*** in the formal/legal context of [both parties to a contract agreeing on something...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when%20both%20parties%20agree%2Cwhenever%20both%20parties%20agree&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

Clearly the "emphatic" form rarely occurs there. But [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when%20you%20like%2Cwhenever%20you%20like&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) the same choice in the informal context of *at any time...*

[image]

...where the emphatic version has actually become the *most* common choice of phrasing. It's not that ***whenever*** is particularly "informal" - more that legal texts tend to avoid "emphatic" phrasing (probably because *on average* it increases ambiguity).